# RecylerView Adapter Override methods not being called

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, overriding, adapter

```
public class HashTagSearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HashTagSearchAdapter.HashTagViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    List<TagSearchObject> tagResponses;

    public HashTagSearchAdapter (Context context, List<TagSearchObject> tagResponses){
        this.context = context;
        this.tagResponses = tagResponses;
        for (int i =0;i<tagResponses.size();i++){
            Log.e("tagfor",tagResponses.get(i).toString());
        }
        Log.e("constructor",tagResponses.size()+"");
        Log.e("constructor","here");

    }

    @Override
    public HashTagViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tag_search_list,parent,false);
        Log.e("onCreate","here");
        return new HashTagViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HashTagViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TagSearchObject userTagResponse = tagResponses.get(position);
        Log.e("tag",userTagResponse.toString());
        holder.name.setText(userTagResponse.getName());
        holder.count.setText(userTagResponse.getChallengeCount()+" public posts");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.e("getItemCount",this.tagResponses.size()+"");
        return tagResponses.size();
    }


    class HashTagViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView hashtag;
        TextView name,count;
        public HashTagViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            count = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.count);
        }
    }
}
```

here logcat is :

```
 E/tagfor:TagSearchObject{id='1', name='hahah', challengeCount='1'}
 E/constructor: 1
 E/constructor: here
```

Comment: How do you know it is not calling ?

Comment: because you are just calling the constructor not setting it to recycler, add more code and make a clear question

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not added a layout manager and/or your recycler view is not visible. Since it's not visible, no attempt to draw is made and itemCount is never called because, well, there is nothing to draw.

Comment: LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
HashTagSearchAdapter hashTagSearchAdapter = new HashTagSearchAdapter(context,tagSearchObjects);
recyclerView.setAdapter(hashTagSearchAdapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

Answer (score 0):

set `layout manager` before `setAdapter` to the `RecyclerView`

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());   
HashTagSearchAdapter hashTagSearchAdapter = new    
HashTagSearchAdapter(context,tagSearchObjects); 
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
recyclerView.setAdapter(hashTagSearchAdapter);
```

Comment: Doesn't help. Same result

Comment: @try to add more data in your recyclerview adapter